# (ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'blah' could not be found

Tags: azure-cli, azure-acr

when I run an `az acr show` I get:

> PS C:\Users\blah> az acr show
> (ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'blah' could not be found.
> Code: ResourceGroupNotFound
> Message: Resource group 'blah' could not be found.

I do have multiple subscriptions and my default subscription is correct; reference: [(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group '????' could not be found when creating an azure media services account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418223/resourcegroupnotfound-resource-group-could-not-be-found-when-creating-a).

---

The resource group it says it can't find is in another subcription.  Where is it getting the default resource group from?

Reference: [az acr show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-show)

```
az acr show --name
            [--resource-group]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is it getting the default resource group from?

Apparently, I set my **default** resource group:

```
PS C:\Users\blah> az configure -l
[
  {
    "name": "group",
    "source": "C:\\Users\\blah\\.azure\\config",
    "value": "wrong-resource-group"
  }
]
```

> defaults.group The default resource group to use for all commands.

reference: [CLI configuration with az config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration#cli-configuration-with-az-config)